# The projector augmented wave (PAW) method, pseudopotentials (PP), and exchange correlation functionals

Tags: density-functional-theory, pseudopotentials, gpaw, exchange-correlation, projector-augmented-wave

**Disclaimer: Assume the questioner is a novice in DFT**

Is PAW an improvement over the pseudopotential method? In terms of Perdew, Burke, and Ernzerhof (PBE) parameterization, what is the difference between PAW-PBE and GGA-PBE?

Comment: Related answer: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1986/5. Particularly the part starting with "There is no systematic manner for deciding which pseudopotential is ‘better’ as a pseudopotential..."

Comment: That was a nicely detailed answer. That still leaves the PBE part out. Also, I've started putting these disclaimers so answers would become novice-friendly. No harm in having the same question twice on the SE; one for seasoned DFTers, another for rookies.

Comment: This question could use more clarity. "Is PAW an improvement over the pseudopotential method" would be a good standalone question for the site (although it has a partial answer already as @NikeDattani notes). I'm not sure what the second part is asking - perhaps you could elaborate and ask it as a separate question?

Comment: @wcw, your suggestion will make this a better question but will make Jack's answer seem misplaced. Should I edit his answer to include the original question?

Comment: I am not a moderator so I don't want to overstep, but here is one idea. Maybe this question could be something like "what is the relationship between PAW/pseudopotentials and XC functionals?", assuming I've understood your intent correctly. And then you could ask "Is PAW an improvement over the pseudopotential method?" as a separate question since Jack's answer doesn't really address that part anyway.

Answer (score 3):

PAW is proposed to deal with the interaction between electrons and ions. However, PBE or GGA (PBE just one kind of GGA) is just the exchange-correlation functional. You can think PAW and PBE are related to the two different terms in the Kohn-Sham equation. So your question is totally meaningless because you are comparing two completely different concepts.

Comment: Understood. I have a doubt, though. When a PP file says PAW-PBE, does it mean it uses the PAW method for the ion-electron interaction and GGA-PBE as the xc functional?

Comment: Yes. For example, the POTCAR for each element in VASP contains information for pseudopotential and exchange-correlation.

Comment: PAW involves more than just the electron/ion interaction. For example, it allows determination of all-electron kinetic energies.

Comment: @wcw What's information contained POTCAR of VASP? Except for exchange-correlation functional and pseudopotential.

Comment: Projectors, all-electron basis functions, pseudized basis functions, core densities, augmentation charge info, etc. And this is a little pedantic, but strictly PAW isn't a pseudopotential method - it's all-electron (usually with a frozen core). So the PAW transformation affects every term in the energy functional.